# GWT project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

How to export GWT project to file system, and then how to import that project to new eclipse workspace

Answer (score 4):

Export: File -> export-> General\File System.
Import: File -> import-> Existing Project into Workspace -> choose corresponding folder and click ok.